# Running batch file with python script

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a batch file, which I'm trying to run with python and it doesn't work for some reason.
The batch file specifies path, then executes a certain command, like this:

```
Path= %systemdrive%\somefolder\secondfolder\Step1
setupEP.exe ADDLOCAL="tp"
```

Then python script should this file and then does some other things, which are irrelevant for the current some other similar files.
The problem is batch files aren't been executed.
Below is my python script

```
def func1():

    os.popen(r"%systemdrive%\s1.bat")
def func1():

    os.popen(r"%systemdrive%\s2.bat")

list=[func1(),func2()]

for i in list:
    t1=threading.Thread(target=i, args=(1,))
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
```

If I substitute the batch execution with some random loop, like

```
for i in range(0,60):
     print i
```

Everything works perfectly
Help anyone?

Comment: Don't overwrite `PATH`. Update it instead `set "PATH=%systemdrive%\somefolder\secondfolder\Step1;%PATH%"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Thread` should receive a callable object, you are passing `func1()` which is the result of the object *after* being called.

You basically need `my_list = [func1, func2]`

In your case, the batch files run only once on script start, not during your `for` loop.

Comment: 1. How do you explain then, that my script runs counting to 60? 2. That doesn't explain why batch files aren't been executed. They should have been executed at least one time

Comment: They aren't being executed because you call them only once. Your `for` loop does run 60 times. Pass them a callable! Pass`func` not `func()`.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling the batch file instead of opening it. Try something like

```
call("PathToFile/File.bat")
```